# Printing text to a textfield in java

Tags: java, eclipse, text, swt

I am still working on that program where i asked a question about yesterday.

So i have this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shlKoffieHalenApp = new Shell();
    shlKoffieHalenApp.setMinimumSize(new Point(610, 430));
    shlKoffieHalenApp.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_NORMAL_SHADOW));
    shlKoffieHalenApp.setSize(610, 430);
    shlKoffieHalenApp.setText("Koffie Halen App");
    shlKoffieHalenApp.setLayout(null);

    List list = new List(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.BORDER);
    list.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Sans", 13, SWT.BOLD));
    list.setItems(new String[] {"Anne", "", "Bas", "", "Daan", "", "Nick", "", "Paul", "", "Peter", "", "Sebastien"});
    list.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
    list.setBounds(10, 10, 113, 377);

    ButtonAnne = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.CHECK);
    ButtonAnne.setBounds(129, 17, 137, 16);
    ButtonAnne.setText("Aanwezig/Afwezig");

    ButtonBas = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.CHECK);
    ButtonBas.setBounds(129, 67, 137, 16);
    ButtonBas.setText("Aanwezig/Afwezig");

    ButtonDaan = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.CHECK);
    ButtonDaan.setBounds(129, 120, 137, 16);
    ButtonDaan.setText("Aanwezig/Afwezig");

    ButtonNick = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.CHECK);
    ButtonNick.setBounds(129, 173, 137, 16);
    ButtonNick.setText("Aanwezig/Afwezig");

    ButtonPaul = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.CHECK);
    ButtonPaul.setBounds(129, 224, 137, 16);
    ButtonPaul.setText("Aanwezig/Afwezig");

    ButtonPeter = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.CHECK);
    ButtonPeter.setBounds(129, 276, 137, 16);
    ButtonPeter.setText("Aanwezig/Afwezig");

    ButtonSebastien = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.CHECK);
    ButtonSebastien.setBounds(129, 329, 137, 16);
    ButtonSebastien.setText("Aanwezig/Afwezig");

    ButtonKoffie = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.NONE);
    ButtonKoffie.setBounds(394, 53, 121, 34);
    ButtonKoffie.setText("Klik voor koffie!");

    Answer = new Text(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.BORDER);
    Answer.setEditable(false);
    Answer.getText();
    Answer.setBounds(355, 106, 200, 30);

    shlKoffieHalenApp.open();
    shlKoffieHalenApp.layout();
    while (!shlKoffieHalenApp.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }

        Random generate = new Random();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); {

        if(ButtonAnne.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Anne");
        }
        if(ButtonBas.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Bas");
        }
        if(ButtonDaan.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Daan");
        }
        if(ButtonNick.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Nick");
        }
        if(ButtonPaul.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Paul");
        }
        if(ButtonPeter.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Peter");
        }
        if(ButtonSebastien.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Sebastien");
        }   

            if(ButtonKoffie.getSelection() == true) {
                int randomIndex = generate.nextInt(names.size());

                Answer.setText(names.get(randomIndex) + " moet koffie halen!");                 

            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer is the textfield where i want to print the random name thats picked from the ArrayList.
What am i missing here? I tried to creat a method but that did not work out as planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put anything in the `SWT` event loop, user interfaces are event driven, you should not use polling.

You should add event listeners to the components, for example if you want to intercept when a button is pressed, you should add a `SelectionListener` to it:

```
buttonKoffie = new Button(shlKoffieHalenApp, SWT.NONE);
buttonKoffie.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {

        // this method is called when the button is pressed 

        int randomIndex = generate.nextInt(names.size());
        answer.setText(names.get(randomIndex) + " moet koffie halen!");  
    }
});
```

Read the documentation of the various components to know which listeners you can add and how they behave.

The [`Button`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FButton.html) documentation also specifies that `getSelection` works only for `CHECK`, `RADIO` and `TOGGLE` buttons, it will always return `false` for `PUSH` buttons.

Another problem of putting code in the `SWT` event loop is that you are continuously re-creating the `names` array, so you will always find it empty. You should create it once and use event listeners of the check buttons to fill it.

Other recommendations:

- adopt the proper Java [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) (for example, the name of the variables should start with a lowercase letter)
- use proper [layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) instead of absolute positioning (you should never have to call `setBounds`)

Comment: Thanks alot! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`Answer.setText(randomIndex + " moet koffie halen!");`

with

`Answer.setText(names.get(randomIndex) + " moet koffie halen!");`

Comment: Not working, it's still not printing the outcome in "Answer".

Comment: What is getting printed?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. But it could be that i made a mistake in the if statements. It could be it's not checking the button properly. I'm not getting any errors though wich makes it even harder.

Comment: If it is not printing anything, your `if` condition is obviously not satisfying. Show us your full method code

Comment: It looks like the 'if' condition can't find the selection 'boolean'

Comment: Are you selecting the 'Kofee' button?

Comment: The ButtonKoffie is the eventual button that gets clicked for the print. Those other buttons are checkboxes. When a checkbox is selected or checked, a name is put into the ArrayList. And when you click or select, the ButtonKoffie, there is 1 name randomly choosen that gets printed. Thats the idea.

Answer (score 0):

this lines of code:

```
 int randomIndex = generate.nextInt(names.size());
 Answer.setText(randomIndex + " moet koffie halen!");
```

are setting in the textView only the random int you got, you need instead the random element in the list... then you need to use `names.get(randomIndex)`